# String cannot be converted to String[] in java

Tags: java

I am new in java. I need to store user input (String) to the string array for some project. I have done the following code but the error is String cannot be converted to String[].

```
public class Customer {

    final int NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMER = 7;
    int MIN_BUY_AMOUNT = 10;
    int MAX_BUY_AMOUNT = 400;

    private String[] name = new String[10];
    private float[] purchaseAmount = new float[10];
    private float[] total = new float[10];

    public Customer() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Groccery");
    }

    public void setCustomerName(int count) {
        System.out.print("Enter the name for Customer " + count + ": ");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        name = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

help me!!!

Comment: You should assign input to some index in array (not entire array). Try: name[count] = in.nextLine(); Also would be nice to check range of count variable before assignment otherwise you can get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you are trying to convert `String` to `String[]`. This is where:

```
name = in.nextLine();
```

The scanner's `nextLine()` method returns a `String`, but you are assigning it to `String[]`. If you want to add this name to the string (which is probably what `int count` is for) you can use:

```
name[count] = in.nextLine();
```

However, you will have to validate `count` because if it's less than 0 or greater than 9 you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays require a index number which should start at 0, for example:

```
name[0] = "John Doe"
name[1] = "Jack Black"
name[2] = "Whoson First"
......... etc.
```

The to get the elemental data from the Array you will need to iterate through it and access each array element by way of that very same index number, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(name[i]);
}
```

In your code you have already established your name array and gave it a size of 10 data elements. So in other words you array will hold up to 10 customer names. Rather limited since it is difficult to force arrays to grow dynamically as more customers names need to be stored into the array (I'm sure there will eventually be more than 10 customers). This is where an ArrayList is better to use because it can grow as required very easily. See JavaDoc's about the ArrayList Class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to put fill your array one by one, but an array is essentially a collection or list of a data type. So you could try something like:

```
for(int x = 0; x < (however many entries you want -1); x++) 
{
     name[x] = in.nextLine();
}
```

Or, you could use your count variable

```
name[count] = in.nextLine();
```

You can not try to equate an array and a string or int without stating where you want to place the value in the array. Arrays begin counting from 0 for the first entry, 1 for the second entry, etc.